# NSNumberFormatter.number for currency format not working in Device but works in simulator

Tags: swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, nslocale, xcode9.2

I've been trying to implement currency format based on passing my custom language identifier.

Below is my code

```
func currencyFormatter(language:String, amount:String)  -> String  {

    let nsFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    nsFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    nsFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
    var formattedString: String?
    var amountInNumber:NSNumber!
    if let number = nsFormatter.number(from: amount)
    {
        amountInNumber = number.doubleValue as NSNumber
    }
    nsFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: language)
    formattedString = ((amountInNumber?.intValue) != nil) ? nsFormatter.string(from: amountInNumber) : amount

    guard let finalString = formattedString else {
        return ""
    }
    return finalString
}
```

I am trying to pass language as "fr-FR" and amount as "1234.45" then expecting output is "1 234,45".

This is working fine in simulator but not working in device (returning same value 1234.45)

Do i missed anything. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decimal separator is locale-dependent, therefore parsing "1234.45"
fails if the locale's separator is not a period.

It the input string uses a fixed format with a period as decimal separator
then you can set the formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" for the conversion 
from a string to a number. Then set it to the desired locale for the conversion
from number to a string.

Example:

```
func currencyFormatter(language: String, amount: String)  -> String  {

    let nsFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    nsFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    nsFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

    guard let number = nsFormatter.number(from: amount) else {
        return amount
    }

    nsFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: language)
    nsFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

    return nsFormatter.string(from: number) ?? amount
}

print(currencyFormatter(language: "fr-FR", amount: "1234.45"))
// 1 234,45 €
```